# Request and response seem wrong when using grunt express and ws

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, grunt-express

I am using [express](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express) and [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws).

I am able to get it up and running, but when I use app.use(fn) it doesn't seem to use the request and response objects from express, so I am getting errors when I call req.get (to get a request header) and similarly res.status.

To debug I tried running it without grunt-express, but the request and response are correct. Has anyone faced this problem or knows how to fix it?

snippet of code that relates to using grunt-express:

```
exports = module.exports = app;
app.listen = function() {
    return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

I realize that the above snippet is not exactly what is told in the README of grunt-express, but:

```
server.use = function () {
    return app.use.apply(app, arguments);
}
```

Did not work for me, because grunt-express relied on so much more.

I am also open to use any library you have tried out that lets me run an express server while allowing me to hot load the front-end on development.